# Multiple lines for marriage in genealogytree

Tags: line-breaking, genealogytree

I'm using the genealogytree package and want to use multiple lines as family label (where you normally write data like marriage)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label={\gtrsymMarried~first line\\another line}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I tried, but the package ignores the line break. What can I do about it?

Comment: fully compilable MWE. you know the drill.

Comment: @naphaneal Sure, thx. for pointing out!

Comment: @naphaneal ah, if it just was always that easy to get an MWE from OPs. It would be so refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options for labels can be given by `label options`. These a TikZ node options.

For multiline text, you need something like `align=center`.

The following shows an application with some more options to play:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
    label options={align=center,font=\footnotesize,
      inner sep=1pt,fill=white,opacity=0.75,text opacity=1}
    ]{
    child[family label={\gtrsymMarried~first line\\another line}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good also with opacity. +1.

Comment: Why two times "label options"?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain No need for both - just a relict from the original code, sorry. I updated the code now.

Answer (score 6):

To allow linebreaks, you can insert a vertical box, for example a `minipage` or a `\parbox`. These require you to specify the width of the box but you probably want this to be automatically determined, so you can use the `pbox` package to get a `parbox`, which automatically shrinks to the required width. You still have to specify a maximum line width. I would just use `\textwidth`, but you can insert a more smaller dimension to get automatic linebreaking if a line is too long:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label=\pbox{\textwidth}{\gtrsymMarried~first line\\another line}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

% If you prefer a centered symbol:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label=\gtrsymMarried\scriptsize~\pbox{\textwidth}{first line\\another line}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With stacks or TABstacks, you can obtain a variety of appearances:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label={\Longstack{\gtrsymMarried~first line\\another line}}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label={\scriptsize\tabbedLongstack[l]{\gtrsymMarried&first line\\&next line}}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label={\gtrsymMarried\scriptsize\ \Centerstack[l]{first line\\next line}}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,label options={fill=white,node font=\footnotesize}]{
    child[family label={\gtrsymMarried\setstackgap{L}{5.5pt}\tiny\ \Centerstack[l]{first line\\next line\\last line}}]{
        g[female]{me}
        p[male]{my husband}
        c[female]{our lovely daughter}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: EXCELLENT ALSO YOUR CODE. +1.